# Start an Approval Flow from a SharePoint List item - Use Approval App in Teams - Add attachments

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, approval-process, microsoft-teams, item-attachment

I would like to create an approval flow that starts when a user changes a column in SharePoint list from "Pending" to "Send for approval". The item in list, will also have attachments and I need these to be included in the approval card. I run the below flow but the attachment doesn't appear in the approval app in teams:
[image]
[image]

Your help will be much appreciated!
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Hi Andriana, you could link to the attachment instead of attaching it (provided that the reciever has access to the list item). Right now the attachment wont be added to the Teams notification :(

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will use the link instead of attaching it